# According to Vishnu Puran, Vishnu created Shiva and according to Shiva Purana it's vice versa. What's the truth?

Tags: puranas, shiva-purana, vishnu-purana, durga

According to Vishnu Puran, Lord Vishnu created Lord Shiva and according to Shiva Purana it's vice versa. In Devi Bhagavata Purana, Adi Shakti created both Lord Vishnu and Lord Shiva. So, what is the actual truth?

Comment: see my question https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8527/supreme-brahman-in-hinduism

Comment: Vishnu(Brahman) created Rudra (not Shiva) and Shiva(Brahman) created Narayana( may be called as lesser vishnu). Shiva purana explicitly mentions Shiva as Brahman and Rudra aka Shankara as amsa of him.

Comment: @AnilKumar I wish you may elaborate this as an answer!

Comment: @pbvamsi some people will not accept this as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Vishnu,Shiva and Brahma are form of Brahman. They are not different. Once Rishi Markandeya told Parvati's parents King Himavan and Menavati the story of Brahma,Vishnu and Shiva. In the story,Himavan and Menavati found that Brahma,Vishnu and Shiva are same.

Answer (score 1):

> "quantum space time is a superposition: a quantum superposition of an
> infinite number of space times, all happening at the same time."

So, all 3 possibilities from 3 scriptures are true. Human beings however, prefer not picking a sect that suits one's temperament and cherish this limited short life, rather waste time trying to validate "Who created Who" as if people on social media and internet are realized Buddhas. For one to validate "The Truth", one has to cover all the possibilities of the Infinite, because leaving out even a single possibility would be an incomplete conclusion.

Sects were created so that like minded people can practice rituals together and support each other, share, and climb the spiritual ladder. Not put one sect in a death match with the other.

Source: Since this question already provided the source of three scriptures, and each sect can validate their own claim using one's chosen scriptures, the response is generic and is not biased towards one single scripture, consequently any attempt to force the answer towards any one of them is also biased. Any attempt to use a fouth scripture would be to invalidate this question since it only uses 3 scriptural reference.

Answer (score 0):

According to Srimad Bhagavatam written by A.C Bhaktivedanta Srila Prabhupada, Lord Brahma came from navel of supreme personality of God head Sri Maha Vishnu .
Lord brahma created the four kumaraya & told them to take responsibility of the procreation of the universe. They did not obey him. So Lord Brahma Ji got angry & from his eye brows came a baby crying. That is Lord Rudra.   ( Lord Shiva )
He is the Lord of destruction. 
Lord Vishnu is the maintainer.

Answer (score 0):

It's all due to Kalpa Bheda.

Shiva Purana 7.1.13.:

> 12. I shall narrate how Rudra was born and how Brahmā and Viṣṇu were born from each other.
>
> 13-15. The three are the Ātmans as causes born of Maheśvara; they are the causes of creation, sustenance and annihilation of the universe consisting of the mobile and immobile beings. Endowed with great qualities they are sanctified by the great lord. Presided over by his Śakti they can always perform their activities. Brahmā can create; Viṣṇu can protect; Rudra can annihilate.
>
> 16-21. But they rivalled with one another. Desirous of excelling one another they propitiated their father, the supreme lord by means of penance. Attaining all round favour of the lord at the outset in a former Kalpa, Rudra created Brahmā and Viṣṇu. In another Kalpa, Brahma created Rudra and Viṣṇu. In another Kalpa Viṣṇu created Rudra and Brahmā. Thus in different Kalpas, Brahmā, Viṣṇu and Rudra desiring mutual benefit are born of one another. Based on the events in their respective Kalpas, their process in being the cause of origin of one another is extolled by the sages. Now listen to their holy and wonderful story that releases from sins.

All Puranas belongs to different different kalpas.

Chapter 53 of Matsya Purana mentions Kalpas of all Puranas except Brahma and Markandeya Puranas.

> Padma Purana - Padma Kalpa (hence the name)
>
> Vishnu Purana - Varaha Kalpa (current Kalpa)
>
> Vayu Purana (includes Shiva Purana) - Sveta Kalpa
>
> (Devi) Bhagavata Purana - Sarsvata Kalpa
>
> Naradiya Purana - Brhat Kalpa
>
> Agni Purana - Isana Kalpa
>
> Bhavishya Purana - Aghora Kalpa
>
> Brahma Vaivarata Purana - Rathantara Kalpa
>
> Linga Purana - Agneya Kalpa
>
> Varaha Purana - Manava Kalpa
>
> Skanda Purana - Satpurusha Kalpa
>
> Vamana Purana - Kurma Kalpa
>
> Kurma Purana - Lakshmi Kalpa
>
> Matsya Purana - Vaivastara Manvantara of Varaha Kalpa
>
> Brahmanda Purana - Future Kalpas (No specific name mentioned)

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..