# Who created the Universe?

Tags: krishna, gods, creation, shakti

There is a contrasting description of the creator of the universe. In Devi Purana, it is mentioned that Devi is the creator of the universe, and everything emanates from her.

In Gita, Krishna said that he is the creator of the universe, and everything emanates from him. He also showed his Viswaroopa form to Arjuna.

So, who is the true master/creator of the universe?

If this theory is viewed from the scientific angle, Devi (or *Shakti*/energy) has to be the master of the universe. And all matter has evolved from her. As we know, mass evolves from energy through the `E = mc2` formula (Albert Einstein).

Comment: See [Supreme Brahman in Hinduism](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8527/3500)

Comment: @iammilind: This is not a duplicate. I am asking on scientific lines.

Comment: @AnilKumar: Supreme Brahman in Hinduism does explain the concept in scientific lines.

Comment: @InduBhusanNath Scientific Speculation is not allowed on this site.  See [this answer on Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-exactly-is-the-story-behind-the-Shiva-Linga-in-the-Hindu-mythology/answer/Diya-V-Sharma). [She](https://www.quora.com/profile/Diya-V-Sharma) wrote many answers on Mythology and Shiva on Scientific basis.

Comment: Devi and Krishna are considered as a form of supreme brahman.
It doesn't matter from whom everything emanates because they are one and the same

Comment: @AnilKumar: Thanks for your quora link..it is very informative

Comment: Shakti is E=mc². HaHaHa. Shakti is not the Energy we read of in Physics, and Shiva is not a bunch of atoms. This "Shakti" is not like the energy we derive from coal, wood, nuclear reactions et cetera. The Shakti we talk of in Shastras is a whole different thing, it is not Energy which is mass×velocity². The Devas are not composed of atoms or matter, but still, if this "Shakti" forsakes them, they become inert. This Shakti is a different​ thing and cannot be comprehended by Science, Physics, or Words.

Answer (score 0):

Actually,Lord Brahma had created the universe and that's why it is also called Brahmand. Lord Brahma is considered as the creator of the world. But we did not worship him because Lord Shiva had given a curse to Brahma that nobody will worship him.Brahma is the creator of the universe and of all beings, as depicted in the Hindu cosmology. The Vedas, the oldest and the holiest of Hindu scriptures, are attributed to Brahma, and thus Brahma is regarded as the father of dharma.
He is not to be confused with Brahman which is a general term for the Supreme Being or Almighty God. Although Brahma is one of the Trinity, his popularity is no match to that of Vishnu and Shiva. Brahma is to be found to exist more in scriptures than in homes and temples. In fact it is hard to find a temple dedicated to Brahma. One such temple is located in Pushkar in Rajasthan.