# Who is the supreme God according to the Varaha Purana?

Tags: varaha-purana

Who is the supreme God according to the Varaha Purana?
Is Lord Shiva the supreme God in the Varaha Purana?

Comment: Thought it doesn’t specifically answer your question you can have a look at: [Is the Vedic Supreme god different from Puranic Supreme God](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/43910/is-the-vedic-supreme-god-different-from-the-puranic-supreme-god/43915#43915), Varaha Purana is mainly dedicated to Vishnu Bhagwan.

Comment: Varaha Purana talks about the Varaha incarnation of Lord Vishnu, so it will say Lord Vishnu is the supreme God.

Comment: Can you give example

Comment: Varaha Purana is a conversation between Varaha and Bhudevi. There she says Vishnu is the supreme god. On pralaya everything goes into Vishnu and again when the world is to be created Brahma is formed and he creates. They call Vishnu nirguna, etc.