# Who is Supreme?

Tags: brahman

For Vaishnavites Vishnu is the Supreme, Brahman
For Shivaites Shiva is the Supreme, Brahman

If we ourself have confusion in Hinduism who is the supreme, how can we explain to a person who is new to Hinduism ?

Comment: It’s not tough. No confusion. All are supreme and forms of the same supreme. Have a look at this answer here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/43910/is-the-vedic-supreme-god-different-from-the-puranic-supreme-god/43915#43915. However one must note if you have a particular isht, then you must completely surrender to him and him only while at the same time not disrespecting other forms of the supreme.

Comment: Hi, a very warm Welcome to HSE! Kindly have a look at the [HSE HELP CENTER](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help), **specifically** the [How does New User get Started on HSE](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se) and also, [HSE FAQ INDEX](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/478/faq-index-for-hinduism-stack-exchange). Please go through them and get started in here properly. Have an enriching journey ahead!

Comment: In terms of actual experience - as reported by practitioners like Ramana Maharishi - Supreme Brahman is formless and nameless.  All personal deities are the result of belief and visions - which vary by sect/personal preference.

Comment: Retated : https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/43915/22556 and possibly a duplicate